# Error when switching from magrittr to native pipes

Tags: r, pipe, stringr, magrittr

I have

```
explanatory_vars<-c("age", "bmi")
outcome<-"Surv(time = mytime, event = myevent)"
```

Why does this work

```
explanatory_vars %>%
  str_c(paste(outcome," ~ ", sep=""), .)
```

whereas this

```
explanatory_vars |> 
  str_c(paste(outcome," ~ ", sep=""), .)
```

throws an error?

```
Error in str_c(explanatory_vars, paste(outcome, " ~ ", sep = ""), .) : 
  object '.' not found
```

I was under the impression that `%>%` and `|>` are interchangeable.

Comment: The dot syntax is not supported with the native pipe. https://www.r-bloggers.com/2021/05/the-new-r-pipe/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can specify a named argument with `_`.  With `str_c`, it is a variadic argument (`...`), so we need to backquote it

```
library(stringr)
explanatory_vars |>
  str_c(paste(outcome," ~ ", sep=""), `...` = _)
```

-output

```
[1] "Surv(time = mytime, event = myevent) ~ age" 
[2] "Surv(time = mytime, event = myevent) ~ bmi"
```

---

Or another option is to have a lambda function

```
explanatory_vars |> 
   {\(x) str_c(paste(outcome," ~ ", sep=""), x)}()
```

-output

```
[1] "Surv(time = mytime, event = myevent) ~ age" 
[2] "Surv(time = mytime, event = myevent) ~ bmi"
```

---

Or another option with `reformulate`

```
explanatory_vars |>
    sapply(reformulate, response = outcome)
```

-output

```
$age
Surv(time = mytime, event = myevent) ~ age
<environment: 0x7fce8fbee740>

$bmi
Surv(time = mytime, event = myevent) ~ bmi
<environment: 0x7fce8fbee740>
```